# Amazon AWS - Auto Scaling Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

Since some weeks ago, I've been studying a lot about AWS. Recently, I've been running some tests with **Auto Scaling for EC2**, using applications with HTML front end and JS back end. So far, I've been using S3 to create an URL in which users can access the HTML front end. The HTML is connected to an Elastic Beanstalk instance's endpoint, allowing me to send requests to my EC2 instances, already auto scaled and connected to a RDS instance. It's a simple architecture, allowing my users to access the site, require data and get the response, with the Auto Scaled EC2 keeping a good relation between my costs and my app's performance;

Recently, though, I was requested to develop a similar system, but for a Wordpress site. Problem here is, since Wordpress is basically PHP, I wouldn't be able to use S3 properly. So, my question basically is: **how could I develop an Auto Scaling system in Amazon AWS for my Wordpress site, preferably without using Elastic Beanstalk (since my boss is afraid it can get too expansive)**? It's important to notice that the site has constant updates in its content. If possible, I would like to use a similar architecture to the one I developed, but I'm okay if that's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk does not have a cost for itself, just the services that you use. For your use case EB is just fine.

The key with Wordpress (build your own or EB) is to separate the database from the EC2 instances. Auto Scaling will launch and terminate instances using a precofigured AMI that you specify. The database needs to be independent from the EC2 instances. I recommend RDS for this for high availability and fault tolerance.

There are numerous articles on the Internet for AWS and Wordpress. You can even use CloudFormation to build everything for you. Here are some links to get you started:

Installs and deploys WordPress on to Amazon EC2 instances in an Auto Scaling group with a multi-AZ Amazon RDS database instance for storage.
[Cloudformation Wordpress + Auto Scaling + RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/sample-templates-applications-eu-west-1.html)

Deploying a High-Availability WordPress Website with an External Amazon RDS Database to Elastic Beanstalk
[Elastic Beanstalk + WordPress + Auto Scaling + RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-hawordpress-tutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks, man. I've started the second tutorial, but faced some issues as described [in a question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51425341/wordpress-and-aws-elastic-beanstalk-stuck-in-uploading-application-version). Could you give me a hand?