# Wordpress and AWS - Elastic Beanstalk stuck in "Uploading application version"

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I recently started using Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk to configure Auto Scaling to an Wordpress site. To do so, I've been strictly following [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-hawordpress-tutorial.html). But when I attempt to Upload and Deploy my app for the first time (as explained in tutorial's step *"Configure and Deploy Your Application"*), I get stuck with Beanstalk running the deploy, without completing it. There's no troubleshooting, just this continuous deploy. Does anyone have any idea what could be going on?

EDIT 1 - An update: after 15 minutes trying to deploy, it stopped by itself, throwing the errors:

```
Creating security group ingress named: AWSEBSecurityGroupSSHIngress failed Reason: CIDR block <MY_TOO_SENSITIVE_TO_DISPLAY_IP> is malformed (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: <MY_TOO_SENSITIVE_TO_DISPLAY_ID>)
```

And

```
Creating security group ingress named: sshfromhome failed Reason: CIDR block <MY_TOO_SENSITIVE_TO_DISPLAY_IP> is malformed (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: <MY_TOO_SENSITIVE_TO_DISPLAY_ID>)
```

Comment: The part that you did not display is where the error is. Try to show by just modifying some digits while still allowing us to see the error. Your CIDR block should look like 8.8.8.8/32

Comment: Not only should the CIDR representation look valid, but it must also be valid. The quickest way to validate the block is to try creating a Security Group ingress group manually through the Security Groups console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it was a dumb mistake of mine: I wrote the IP's in the `.extensions/dev.config` file using the format `X.X.X.X`, instead of the correct CIDR block pattern `X.X.X.X/X`.

Comment: Tried to, but yesterday I answered an old question of mine, so StackOverflow will only let me mark this one as answer in two days...